# node.js based library for scientific unit conversion

Tags: node.js, npm, unit-conversion

before reinventing the wheel i'm asking the crowd if anyone knows a node.js 
library (MIT) for scientific unit conversion. the library should cover the following topics:

- Power
- Heat rate / Efficiency
- Energy / Work / Torque Temperature
- absolut Temperature difference
- Mass
- Length
- Area
- Volume
- Pressure
- Time
- Speed
- Mass flow
- Volume flow
- Density Specific enthalpy / Heating value, based on mass
- Heating value, based on volume
- Wobbe index
- Thermal conductivity

all unit conversion libs i found so far are focused on specific topic (eg. color).

what i think of is more like a universal lib, similar to lodash - which consists of tiny little modules that can be required separately.

all suggestion are welcome
regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a general module that does what you need. You may need to create one.

If you end up (re)inventing the wheel, then you can take a look at the [Frink](https://frinklang.org/) language that you can use to make the conversion, or at least you can use its [amazing database of measurement units](https://frinklang.org/frinkdata/units.txt) that can convert pretty much everything.